# Multiple, identical elements in the same C# DTO

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF-service, which can return me an XML document looking something like this:

```
<alert>
    <identifier>SecretID</identifier>
    <info>
        <valueName>Name1</valueName>
        <value>Info1</value>
    </info>
    <info>
        <valueName>Name2</valueName>
        <value>Info2</value>
    </info>
</alert>
```

The DTO of this file would look something like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "alert", Namespace = "")]
public class Alert
{
    [DataMember(Name = "identifier")]
    public string identifier { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "info")]
    public List<Info> Info { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "info", Namespace = "")]
public class Info
{
    [DataMember(Name = "valueName")]
    public string ValueName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I try with the following:

```
var alert = new Alert()
{
    Identifier = "SecretID",
    Info = new List<Info>
    {
        new Info() {ValueName = "Name1", Value = "Info1"},
        new Info() {ValueName = "Name2", Value = "Info2"},
    }
}
```

I get:

```
<alert>
    <identifier>SecretID</identifier>
    <info>
        <info xmlns="">
            <valueName>Name1</valueName>
            <value>Info1</value>
        </info>
        <info xmlns="">
            <valueName>Name2</valueName>
            <value>Info2</value>
        </info>
    </info>
</alert>
```

I don't need the extra `<info>` tag, and the namespace `xmlns=""` would be nice to have removed too. What should I do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary or key value pairs as mentioned below:

```
[DataContract(Name = "alert", Namespace = "")]
public class Alert
{
    [DataMember(Name = "identifier")]
    public string identifier { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "info")]
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> Info { get; set; }
}

var alert = new Alert()
{
    Identifier = "SecretID",
    Info = new KeyValuePair<string, string>()
}
```

Comment: This looks promissing - what if the ``KeyValuePair`` is a complex type (class)?